# added a new hard drive to my Windows 7 system, where do I go to format it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, formatting

added a new 1tb drive to my system. It shows up in BIOS fine, but not in Explorer.

Where do I go to format the drive, I can't find the utility on Windows 7.

Comment: Mac has Disk Utility, Linux has GParted et al, but what does Windows use? That I don't know. I always booted from a Linux LiveCD for this problem.

Answer (score 6):

If the drive is not showing up in explorer its likely because its not formatted in a format that Windows recognizes.  You can open the Disk Management console by running diskmgmt.msc from the run dialog.  You should then see your new disk there.  You can then create a new partition and format it as you would like.

Alternatively, if you like the command line you can use the diskpart.exe utility.

Comment: Alternately you can right click on My Computer and go to Manage. Then under Storage > Disk Managemnt you can format the drive.